# Can't get HTML element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck trying to retrieve the selected value from a 'select' element via javascript. I can't even get the element from the DOM with either jQuery or document.getElementById().
Here is my code:

```
   function getDropdown(headerText, options, id) {
      var container = document.createElement('div');
      container.setAttribute('class', 'nfvo-drop-down-container');

      var dd = document.createElement('select');
      $(dd).attr('id', id);
      for(var val in options) {
          $('<option />', {value: val, text: options[val]}).appendTo(dd);
      }

      if(headerText) {
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.setAttribute('class', 'panel-header');
          span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(headerText));
          container.appendChild(span);
      }

      container.appendChild(dd);
      return container;
   }
   var dd = getDropDown('My dropdown', [1,2,3,4], 'ddID);
   var e = document.getElementById('ddID');
   var e2 = $('#ddID');
   var e3 = $('#ddID').val();
   var e4 = $('#ddID').text();
```

If I were to console.log these values I would get these results:

```
console.log(e) -> 'null'
console.log(e2) -> <Got the element>
console.log(e3) -> 'undefined'
console.log(e4) -> <Nothing, just a blank>
```

Any ides on what might cause this problem? 
This block of code is within a '.then' function call e.g:

```
$.when(...).then(function(...)
   <Here is the code>
);
```

**EDIT:** There was a typo in the post which have now been fixed. This is not the source of my problem.

I should also mention that I add this div to a ContentPane via the Dojo toolkit and I can see dropdown in the DOM via the inspection tool in chrome.

Comment: there's a typo in code on line var e = document.getElemetnById('ddID');:
its 'getElementById'

Comment: Please, use the console to debug.

Comment: Beside that you have a syntax error and  as mentioned a typo in `getElemetnById`:  Why are you sure that `console.log(e2)` shows your element?  The result of `$('#ddID')` wont be `null` or `undefined`  even if not element is found, because `$( ... )`  returns a result set that contains zero or more elements. If `document.getElementById('ddID');` is `null`  then `$('#ddID').length` will be `0`.

Comment: This is what I get back from console.log(e2) -> 'n.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#ddID"}' I presume this is the element in jQuerys eyes? Apparently I am mistaken. I check and  console.log($('#ddID').length) -> 0.

Comment: Where's the HTML markup? There could be a typo in there as well.

Comment: If there are comments which have been addressed and the problems still remain, flag the comments as 'obsolete'(and delete if they're your own, but ONLY if they no longer apply). You don't need to add anything like a notice to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get select box object by using document.getElementById('ddID')
since you have not added your object to any object in the document.

You will get select box object from the dd object by using dd.childNodes[1]

Answer (score 0):

`getDropDown` creates an element with that id, puts it in a div, and then returns the div.

It never adds any of those elements to any element in the `document`.

Thus, when you search the document for an element with the matching id, it isn't there.

Comment: I'm using Dojo for this project and attaching the div to a ContentPane. Is that of importance? I presume dojo adds it to the DOM since I can see the drop down element with the inspect tool in chrome.

Comment: @Edvin — The code you've supplied doesn't add it to the document at all. Maybe the code you haven't shown us is adding it too late.